Python Fastapi Глобальная переменная в контексте потока выполнения запроса
Предположим, бэкенд работает в связке Python+Fastapi и принимает через сокет GET запрос
Вместе с запросом пользователь отправляет идентификатор сессии. Этот идентификатор сессии мне нужен из "глубоких" функций моего приложения.
Скажем, имем такую цепочку вызовов (от контроллера до бизнес-функций приложения)
A -> B -> C -> D
A имеет доступ к этой сессии, так как у него есть ссылка на HttpRequest.
Я могу передать эту ссылку из A в B. Потом из B в C. Потом из C в D.
Но, если только D нужен доступ к этой переменной, чтобы, скажем, сохранить имя отправителя запроса, или авторизовать его, то иметь этот доступ в B C бессмысленно.
Я бы хотел записать эту переменную куда нибудь в оперативную память в A глобально, и обратиться к ней из D, но это сработает, если пользователь всего один. В случае, если придет два запроса в одно время, то эта переменная "перетрется" и возникнет проблема гонки.
Если бы я использовал свой веб-сервер, возможно, я бы мог записать ее в контекст потока, можно ли сделать что-то похожее с fastapi?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Ну а вообще, возвращаясь к теме вопроса — в питоне есть contextvars, который решает обозначенную вами проблему с гонкой, и с помощью contextvars и middleware можно запилить глобальные переменные в контексте текущего запроса (пример с enSO, но актуальность кода не проверял) — если контекст будет гарантированно чиститься после запроса, то можно предположить, что уязвимостей не будет

Но всё же: нужно явно создать контекст, нужно явно не забыть почистить контекст, нужно помнить где какие объекты обращаются к контексту, всё ещё остаётся вероятность словить ошибку по невнимательности... Как по мне, это всё мазохизм какой-то — явно передавать переменные проще и нагляднее и редактор подсвечивает ошибки сразу, ну удобно же!
